# Why won't my javascript hide/show the image based on the make selection?

Tags: javascript, html-select

This is my code. I am preloading the images and want them to be hidden by default, when the option is selected then I want the image to be displayed. Why won't this work?

I have tried researching Java code options (my knowledge is very weak) and this seems to be the one that makes the most sense, however, it will not work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vehiclemake').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'BMW') {
      $("#bmwlogo").show();
    } else {
      $("bmwlogo").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="block-content">
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_make">
      <option value="">-- Make --</option>
      <option value="BMW" selected="">BMW</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_model">
      <option value="">-- Model --</option>
      <option value="3-Series saloon (E21) 315 (1573 cm³, 75 PS)">3-Series saloon (E21) 315 (1573 cm³, 75 PS)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_year">
      <option value="">-- Year --</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="ymm-extra" style="display:none">


    <div class="ymm-category-container">
      <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>



    <div class="ymm-search">

      <div class="ymm-or-search">
        Or search:
      </div>

      <form action="#">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="ymm-td-input" hidden="">
                <input class="input-text ymm-search-field" type="text" name="s" value="">
              </td>
              <td class="ymm-td-button" hidden="">
                <button type="submit" title="Search" class="button"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" title="Search" class="button ymm-submit-any-selection">Search</button>

</div>


<div id="vehicle_selector_selections">
  <img id="bmwlogo" src="https://placehold.it/150x150?text=BMW_LOGO">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: You have duplicate IDs of `vehiclemake`. Browser behavior when it comes to handling identical IDs in the same document is undefined.

Comment: also, `$("bmwlogo").hide();` forgot the #

Comment: As an advice, set the place holder options with the attributes `hidden selected disabled` this will avoid the user selecting them

Comment: also, this is not Java. It's javaScript ( together with jQuery ) No relationship between them. It's like `car` and `carpet`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, jQuery was not loaded in this snippet. Double check you have it included in your project.

Second: ID's should be unique, but you're re-using the same ID through out this code just like you would a class. Change your ID's so that they're unique.

Third: use `$(this).val()` instead as its the 'jQuery' way to get a value.

Fourth: You missed the `#` from the selector on `$("#bmwlogo").hide();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vehicleBrandSelect').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'BMW') {
      $("#bmwlogo").show();
    } else {
      $("#bmwlogo").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#bmwlogo{
 display:none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehicleBrandSelect" class="ymm-select" name="_make">
      <option value="" selected>-- Make --</option>
      <option value="BMW">BMW</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_model">
      <option value="">-- Model --</option>
      <option value="3-Series saloon (E21) 315 (1573 cm³, 75 PS)">3-Series saloon (E21) 315 (1573 cm³, 75 PS)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_year">
      <option value="">-- Year --</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="ymm-extra" style="display:none">


    <div class="ymm-category-container">
      <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>



    <div class="ymm-search">

      <div class="ymm-or-search">
        Or search:
      </div>

      <form action="#">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="ymm-td-input" hidden="">
                <input class="input-text ymm-search-field" type="text" name="s" value="">
              </td>
              <td class="ymm-td-button" hidden="">
                <button type="submit" title="Search" class="button"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" title="Search" class="button ymm-submit-any-selection">Search</button>

</div>


<div id="vehicle_selector_selections">
  <img id="bmwlogo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: The plugin php code generates the ID for all selectors and I have limited knowledge on how to change them individually. Can I use the selector names instead of ID as each of these are unique?

Comment: yeah, like `$('select[name="_make"]')`

Comment: I've made all the changes but still no joy :(

Comment: check console for errors. It works in the code I just posted when you press the 'run code snippet button

Comment: Scrap that, I've got it working :D Thank you so much!

Comment: awesome. If you feel this answer helped, mark it as accepted by pressing the check icon to the top left of this answer

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot `#` for the `$("#bmwlogo")` selector on `.hide();`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#vehiclemake').on('change', function() {
    if (this.value == 'BMW') {
      $("#bmwlogo").show();
    } else {
      $("#bmwlogo").hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block-content">
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_make">
      <option value="">-- Make --</option>
      <option value="BMW" selected="">BMW</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_model">
      <option value="">-- Model --</option>
      <option value="3-Series saloon (E21) 315 (1573 cm³, 75 PS)">3-Series saloon (E21) 315 (1573 cm³, 75 PS)</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="level">
    <select id="vehiclemake" class="ymm-select" name="_year">
      <option value="">-- Year --</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>

  <div class="ymm-extra" style="display:none">


    <div class="ymm-category-container">
      <div class="ymm-clear">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>



    <div class="ymm-search">

      <div class="ymm-or-search">
        Or search:
      </div>

      <form action="#">
        <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="ymm-td-input" hidden="">
                <input class="input-text ymm-search-field" type="text" name="s" value="">
              </td>
              <td class="ymm-td-button" hidden="">
                <button type="submit" title="Search" class="button"><span><span>Search</span></span></button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>

  <button type="button" title="Search" class="button ymm-submit-any-selection">Search</button>

</div>


<div id="vehicle_selector_selections">
  <img id="bmwlogo" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcT3TH-PhVWOSxE2oNWSX4-7Byz90B_rAYtcY1yVWxnKtrI9HdqB">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a bad answer as you're setting OP up to fail due to ID's being non-unique and the logo not having the correct starting CSS

Comment: the id is unique, and the starting css are as the OP give it... the question was about why the hide method fail, and here is the answer

Comment: But you didn't explain that you changed the ID in your example

Comment: I didnt.. The id was unique from OP version. it's never been the problem

Comment: `vehiclemake` it's not Unique...it should be...but...it's not. And yes, it's a problem. A big one.